# Drone in Italy as a tourist - Where/what to do?

Tags: regulations, dji-mavic-2, dji

I am a German citizen and have a hobby drone dji mavic 2 pro. I would like to know how/where I have to do all the paperwork so that I can **as a tourist** fly my toy over Pisa tower and make a short video and take some pictures....

For doing this in Germany, the process is pretty clear. But what about Italy?

I want to avoid things like this here:

[French tourist could face €113,000 fine...](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3531310/That-s-expensive-photo-French-tourist-face-113-000-fine-charged-violating-Italian-aviation-rules-flying-drone-Rome-s-Colosseum.html)

Comment: I think you'll struggle to get a permit to fly around the Tower of Pisa. If you don't get an answer here you might have more luck on [aviation.se], where aeronautical regulations are on topic, or perhaps [drones.se]

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell (as of 30<sup>th</sup> September 2020) Italian drone regulations are available first-hand [here](https://www.enac.gov.it/la-normativa/normativa-enac/regolamenti/regolamenti-ad-hoc/regolamento-mezzi-aerei-pilotaggio-remoto) - but only in Italian; as I am not an Italian speaker you will need to locate a reputable translator (I have browsed briefly with Google Translate, but due to the risks of mistranslation will not copy it here.)

The rules across Europe have largely been harmonised under EASA, so you are likely to find them to be quite similar to your home (German) rules - and so unfortunately flying close to a busy tourist location is likely to be difficult for a recreational flyer.